# V-model directives don't support input type="file"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bind, v-model

I am trying to update the user profile data in my database, but I am stuck at the user profile image. I can't use the v-model for binding, and with v-on:change it doesn't work. This is my code so far, it is working properly, the only issue being the binding.

> ```
> <template>
> -----
>           <div v-if="!image">
>             <h2>Select an image</h2>
>             <input type="file" @change="onFileChange" /> ---->here I would like to use the v-model but can't use it on input type="file"
>           </div>
>           <div v-else>
>             <img :src="image" />
>             <button @click="removeImage">Remove image</button>
>           </div>
>           <input
>             type="text"
>             placeholder="Userame"
>             v-model="user.username"
>             required
>           />
>           <button
>             type="button"
>             class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect"
>             aria-label="Left Align"
>             @click.prevent="updateProfile(user)"
>           >
>             Update profile
>           </button>
>        ---
> </template>
>
> <script>
> export default {
>   data: function () {
>     return {
>       user: {},
>        image: ''
>     };
>   },
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>   methods: {
>     onFileChange(e) {
>       var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
>       if (!files.length)
>         return;
>       this.createImage(files[0]);
>     },
>     createImage(file) {
>       var image = new Image();
>       var reader = new FileReader();
>       var vm = this;
>
>       reader.onload = (e) => {
>         vm.image = e.target.result;
>       };
>       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
>       console.log(file.name);
>     },
>     removeImage: function (e) {
>       this.image = '';
>   },
>     updateProfile() {
>       store
>         .dispatch("updateProfile", {
>           username: this.user.username,
>           email: this.user.email,
>           profileImage: this.file ------>I need it for the binding here
> ```

---

> ```
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to bind the file to `this.file`. Update your `onFileChange` method to this , it will work.

Note: `v-model` only works with `input` which use `value` binding, where input type file doesn't use `input value`, it makes no sense to use `input type file` with v-model

```
onFileChange(e) {
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length) return;
      this.file = files[0]
      this.createImage(this.file);
    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even if I changed the `onFileChange` method, when I `console.log(this.user) `the only field empty remains `profileImage: " "`

Comment: you're not updating file to `user`, you're updating `file` which is data property. Check once

Comment: What you're trying to update `this.file` or `this.user.profileImage` ?